How to save css to persist over loading different pages or refreshing page
I am trying to implement the function of saving a post or liking a post and the css style of the like button or the save button doesn't apply when refreshing or changing page. how can I save the css styles to persist over different pages.
I am using django in the backend
here is my view in django:
def favourite(request, post_id):
    user = request.user
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
    is_favourite = False
    if profile.favourite.filter(id=post_id).exists():
        profile.favourite.remove(post)
        is_favourite = False
    else:
        profile.favourite.add(post)
        is_favourite = True
    response = {
        "is_favourite": is_favourite,
    }
    return JsonResponse(response)

here is the html/css/js part:


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.favourite-button').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var button = $(this);
                var post_id = button.data('id');
                var url = button.attr('href');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    data: {
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.is_favourite) {
                            button.find('i').addClass('liked');
                        } else {
                            button.find('i').removeClass('liked');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        console.error('Error:', response);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
.action-buttons i.liked{
    color: var(--btn-color);
}
                        <div class="action-buttons">
                            <div class="interaction-buttons">
                                <span>
                                    <a href="{% url 'like' post.id %}" class="like-button" data-id="{{ post.id }}">
                                        <i class='bx bxs-heart {% if post.user_liked %} liked {% endif %}'></i>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                                <span><i class='bx bxs-comment-detail'></i></span>
                                <span><i class='bx bxs-share-alt'></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="bookmark">
                                <span>
                                    <a href="{% url 'favourite' post.id %}" class="favourite-button"
                                        data-id="{{post.id}}">
                                        <i class='bx bxs-bookmark'></i>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>




You have different styles for different states, but you don't persist the style, you persist the state.
